# Why a numpy array appears to have no shape?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-tesseract

I understand the following:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])

print(arr.shape)
```

Output:

```
(2, 4)
```

So I was wondering why I get the following:

```
import numpy

import pytesseract
import logging

# Raw call does not need escaping like usual Windows path in python 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger('pytesseract').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


image = r'C:\ocr\target\31832_226140__0001-00002b.jpg'
target = numpy.asarray(pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='--dpi 96 --psm 6 -c preserve_interword_spaces=1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.,- \'" '))
print("target type is:",type(target))
print("target array shape is:",target.shape)
```

Output:

```
DEBUG:pytesseract:['C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract', 'C:\\ocr\\target\\31832_226140__0001-00002b.jpg', 'C:\\Users\\david\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tess_p68ogbz9', '--dpi', '96', '--psm', '6', '-c', 'preserve_interword_spaces=1', '-c', "tessedit_char_whitelist=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.,- '", 'txt']
target type is: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
target array shape is: ()
```

Okay. My array is text. But I still would have thought I would get parameter's example like say `(1,999)` for my shape?

Using the line `print(target)` gives the following type of output.

-------->snip<----------

```
196 ANGUS, Lynne Manon ........................128 Wellington Rd, Wemuomata Recepnonst
        197 ANGUS, Mane Joan .........00... ......129 Wellington Road, Weinumomata, Married
       198 ANGUS, Manon Jean .........................173 Wellington Road, Weinuiomata,Texi Driver
        199 ANGUS. Noel Fulton ........................127 Weinuomats Road, Weinuomate, Carpenter
```

Comment: asarray converts “array like” objects such as lists, tuples, other ndarrays to an ndarray. A string is treated as an object, and if your code is supplying one string, that means you are making an array out of an object. The result has no shape. But that is assuming the input is a single string, I can’t tell from the supplied code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just means that you've created a scalar, i.e., an array with "no shape". Consider:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array(1)
>>> arr
array(1)
>>> arr.shape
()
```

This is because, I can only surmise, `pytesseract.image_to_string` returns a `str` object (or maybe a `bytes` object). So of course, you get:

```
>>> np.asarray("some string object")
array('some string object', dtype='<U18')
>>> np.asarray("some string object").shape
()
```

It isn't clear exactly what you expect to create. As you stated, you just have a text file, presumably, so *why are you trying to create a numpy.ndarray object out of it?* If you can elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, perhaps I or others can suggest an approach.

Comment: I was using numpy arrays to pass the data between functions. I just got into trouble when I tried a simple save to file. numpy functions like  `numpy.savetxt` won't accept scalars eg `ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead`

Comment: `()` is a length 0 tuple, the shape of a 0D array.  It has one element.  `savetxt` is intended to write `csv` files, a 2d like table.

Comment: @Dave "I was using numpy arrays to pass the data between functions" that doesn't really tell me what you were *expecting* to create. And frankly, it doesn't really tell me much, since you certainly don't need to use a numpy array to pass data between functions. Again, here you are getting a bytes object, why don't you just use that? Why you would use `numpy.savetext`. Again, it would really help if you elaborate on what you are actually trying to accomplish

Comment: @Dave like, if you just want to save the data to a file, then you can just use the `open` function to create a file object (in binary mode) and then write the `bytes` object to the file.

Comment: Sorry. I am doing OCR. Electoral Roll mage files (JPG) to text files. I am splitting the images into columns. Rotating and resizing. All my functions are taking & returning numpy array data. It works in well with OpenCV and PIllow calls. Actually I'm almost finished. The example here is just using a simple call to the OCR engine Tesseract.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with the answer provided by @juanpa.arrivillaga.  But to answer the question you're not quite asking:

```
>>> x = np.asarray(['abc'])
>>> x.shape
(1,)
>>> x = np.asarray(list('abc'))
>>> x.shape
(3,)
```